# Disable/enable interrupt (time) when an input is pressed on/off

Tags: c, assembly, input, interrupt, avr

will clearing interrupt/breaking the loop then setting the interrupt, resume the ISR ?
I am still new to formatting, so i'm unsure if this will do it.

```
else if(serial_input == 'p' || serial_input == 'P') {

    while(serial_input = fgetc(stdin)) {
        if(serial_input == 'p' || serial_input == 'P'){
            cli();
            break;
        }
        sei();  
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to manually fire an interrupt with this code, or is this a higher priority ISR that interrupted the current one?  EDIT: Ah never mind, I see what you're doing!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind what sei() and cli() do.  cli() globally sets the interrupt mask, effectively masking all incoming interrupts.  All this will do is "Protect" code prior to the next sei() call from being interrupted.  All interrupts received during this time will NOT be processed as interrupts.  Effectively, they're "ignored" while mask bits are set.  [Here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) is an easy-to-read reference on AVR interrupts, this includes information on sei() and cli() as well as any other interrupt-information I mention below.

You ask about stopping and resuming an ISR, which is in itself a strange question.  When an interrupt is encountered, your current process is STOPPED, a new stack frame is generated with the ISR information, and the interrupt routine is executed, until a return-from-interrupt is encountered.

```
reti()// In AVR-C
```

This loads your user program back in.  There is effectively no (safe) way to "Pause" an ISR and return to the main execution of the program, only to a deeper (higher priority) interrupt.  Look up Nesting interrupts for this.

Comment: avr does not natively support nesting interrupts. this only can be simulated by using `sei()` (on entering an ISR the global interupt enable flag is disabled)  in the ISR but this is not recommended.

Comment: I only answered that in context of "I think you're asking about nesting, so here's the way to do it."  While I understand the AVR compiler doesn't like nesting, it is possible, and sometimes when you only have an AVR, you need to do it.